# How to find multiple solutions for a $2-$variable function using system of equations.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The two equations are

$$\begin{aligned}3x^2-12y=& \ 0\\
3y^2-12x=& \ 0
\end{aligned}$$

Using system of equations find all of the solutions?

I found the first one to be $(0,0).$ The answer key says $(4,4)$ is also a solution. How is the point $(4,4)$ found?

Comment: Substitute x in terms of y

Comment: Notice that there is a symmetry between the two equations.  i.e. we swap the x's and y's.  This suggests that solutions will be found on the line $x = y.$

Answer (score 1):

We have $3x^2-12y=0$ and $3y^2-12x=0$.

Solving for $x$ in the second equation gives us $x=\frac{1}{4}y^2$.

Substituting this into the first equation we have

\begin{align}
3\left(\frac{1}{4}y^2\right)^2-12y&=0\\
3\left(\frac{1}{16}y^4\right)-12y&=0\\
\frac{3}{16}y^4-12y&=0\\
3y(\frac{1}{16}y^3-4)&=0\\
\frac{1}{16}y^3-4&=0\\
y^3&=64\\
y&=4\\
\end{align}
Can you proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

$3x^2 - 12y = 0 => x^2 = 4y$

$3y^2 - 12x = 0 => 4x = y^2$

Multiplying both, $4x^3 = 4y^3$ or $x = y$

Substituting in one of the equations,

$x^2 - 4x = 0 \,$ or $\, x = y = 0, x = y = 4$